# Android custom keyboard, find current typing field position

Tags: android, cursor-position, edittextpreference

Is it possible to find current active input field(EditText) reference or position. I have to show suggestion words while user typing on keyboard, and the suggestion I have to show below the editText which is editing that time,
(sorry for bad English).

Comment: Show your code first.

Comment: My friend I just want to know is it possible to find edittext reference ( which is placed for example in messages app) from my custom keyboard application

Comment: Exactly I have to find cursor (x, y) position

Comment: I don't know how to do it.Sorry.My Keybooard was not the same to yours.